# I have problem with automating test create by Google account using moveToElement

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I try to create a Google account for personal using but click on "for myself" button doesn't work.

> ```
> webdriver.get("http://mail.google.com");
>         WebElement createAccountGoogle = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@class='NlWrkb snByac']"));
>         createAccountGoogle.click();
>         WebElement createAccountGoogleForMe = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@jsname='RZzeR']//div[@class=\"jO7h3c\"]"));
>         Actions builder = new Actions(webdriver);
>         builder.moveToElement(createAccountGoogleForMe).click(createAccountGoogleForMe);
>         Action mouseoverAndClick = builder.build();
>         mouseoverAndClick.perform();
>         builder.moveToElement(createAccountGoogleForMe).click();
> ```

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "it doesn't work". Is there an error?

Comment: Doesn't work a click on "For myself" item.